# Android: Push Notification configuration in Google developer console

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-console-developer

I am trying push notifications in Google Developer Console. Now the Google developer console is completely updated. Previosly I did:

1. Register our application in [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
2. Go to the API, enable `Google Cloud Messaging for Android`
3. Go to Credential, click "Create New key". Then click "server key"
4. Add Example: 000.000.0.0, then create API key (This process is for white listing your URL)
5. Use the genrated API KEY in the config file
6. We will get a sender ID from URL, paste it to GCMConstant.java file

In new Google console UI after creating the Project, I didn't find "**Credintial**", "**Create New key**"

Can any one please give me an idea for the configuration of the new google developer console?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://console.developers.google.com/
2. Go to Api Manager From top-left navigation drawer menu
3. then : Mobile APIs -->Cloud Messaging for Android
4. enable api
5. you will find your desired credentials at left side (second)
6. click credentials
7. click on new credentials and click server key
8. Enter the name of server key (by default server key 1)
9. and click create button and finally you will find your api key . :)

Answer (score 7):

1. Select your project from [Google Console](http://console.developers.google.com)
2. Click **Enable and Manage APIs**

[image]

There you will get **credentials** tab

[image]

simply click on **New credentials** and other things are as usual.